# Using returned Values from a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset

I have a method which returns DataSet.

```
  protected DataSet GetProgramList()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC\\sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Program", cn))
                da.Fill(ds1, "Program");
        }
        return ds1;
    }
```

I want to use a specific column from the DataSet in other Method which is below:

```
protected DataSet GetStudentByProgramID(int programID)
{
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC\\sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Student JOIN Program on Program.ProgramID = Student.ProgramID WHERE ProgramID ="+programID, cn))
            da.Fill(ds2, "Student");
    }
    return ds2;
}
```

For example I want to use, the column **ProgramID** from **Program** Table in *first* method. I know I have to store the returned dataset in a variable but **How**?

Comment: I should have asked before giving answer below why do you need ProgamId column in GetStudentByProgramID

Comment: Well I would be retrieving Students based on their ProgramID.

Comment: But you are already passing just one ProgramID in this GetStudentByProgramID(int programID)

Comment: yes, I know. But it's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you will have `ds1` accessible for `GetStudentByProgramID` method

Then you can use it this way

```
rotected DataSet GetStudentByProgramID(int programID)
{

 DataColumn programId = ds1.Tables[0].Columns["ProgramId"];
//to read row you can iterate from ds1.Table[0].Rows

DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=Daffodils-PC\\sqlexpress;Database=Assignment1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"))
{
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Student WHERE ProgramID ="+programID, cn))
da.Fill(ds2, "Student");
}
return ds2;
}
```

Comment: After understanding your requirement the answer posted will allow you to use ProgamId rows

Comment: System.Data.DataSet does not contain a definition for Table. :/

Comment: sorry it should table with capital 'T' and Tables , ill correct it now in answer

Answer (score 0):

*Why don't you write one query?*

```sql
SELECT programID, LastName, FirstName 
FROM Program JOIN Student ON Program.Id=Student.ProgramId
```

That way, you'll have each student with their programID.

Comment: Well to be frank, It's a requirement to write two methods for an assignment. That's why I am doing this.

Comment: `"SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Student WHERE ProgramID ="+programID`.. do you want result for a **particular** programID ?